# JSTL: String Comparison issue using c:When tag

Tags: java, jsp, jstl

I am facing problem when comparing 2 strings values using C:When tag
I am trying as follow

```
<c:when test="${dbUserName eq uName}">
```

Where,
`dbUserName  = “sohail”`. It is fetching value from db column
`uName = “test”`. This is actually input value on login page
But comparison always giving result true…

Here is complete code

```
<%@ page contentType="text/html" %>
<%@ taglib prefix="c" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core"%>
<%@ taglib prefix="sql" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/sql"%>
<HTML>
<body>
<c:set var='uName' value="${param.username}"/>
<c:set var='uPassword' value="${param.password}"/>
<sql:setDataSource var="db" driver="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver"
url="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/test" user="root" password="sohail"/>
<sql:query var="query1"  dataSource="${db}"
sql="select * from login where loginID = '${uName}'">
</sql:query>
<c:forEach var="row" items="${query1.rows}">
<c:set var='dbUserName' value="${row.loginID}"/>
<c:set var='dbUserPassword' value="${row.password}"/>
</c:forEach>
<c:out value="${uName}"/>
<c:out value="${row.loginID}"/>
<c:out value="${row.password}"/>
<c:choose>
<c:when test="${dbUserName eq uName}">
<c:redirect url="profile1.jsp"/>
</c:when>
<c:otherwise>
<c:redirect url="checlLogin.jsp"/>
</c:otherwise>
</c:choose>
</body> 
</html>
```

Kindly suggest how can I fix comparison problem?

Hi Affe,
Thanks, you're right. The problem has been resolved
i just modified query as follow and it is working fine

```
<sql:query var="query1"  dataSource="${db}"
sql="select * from login">
</sql:query>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You appear to have structured the page such that dbUserName and uName will always be the same.

```
<sql:query var="query1"  dataSource="${db}"
sql="select * from login where loginID = '${uName}'">

<c:set var='dbUserName' value="${row.loginID}"/>
```

Something would be very wrong with your database if you got back a row with a loginID that doesn't equal uName.....! (mySQL's sometimes odd default handling of case matching not withstanding.)

What is it you actually want the page to do?